# Create document from nested array content

Tags: jq

Given the following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ],
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "d",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
]
```

How can this be converted to the following using `jq`?

```json
[
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "a",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "b",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "c",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "d",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
jq 'map(if (.response|type == "array") then .response = .response[] else . end)' file
```

This tests the type of the `response` entry in each element of the top-level array.  If it's an array, the entry is "exploded" or duplicated once for each array element; otherwise, it's left as-is.

The result, given the data in the question (with a problematic comma removed):

```json
[
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "a",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "b",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "c",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  },
  {
    "command": "1",
    "response": "d",
    "guild_id": "guild"
  }
]
```

The same thing, but a bit more cryptic:

```bash
jq 'map(.response = .response[]? // .)' file
```

This duplicates (in the same sense as above) the entry from the top-level array if its `response` entry is an array; otherwise, it's left as-is.